# Using Solr search. How to include what other people have searched for.

Tags: solr, drupal-8

Using Solr 7.5.0
Besides a facet search I also want to return what other people have been searching. For instance on Amazon when you search for something there is a block that says. 
Customers who viewed this item also viewed ...
Mine would be similar to say
Customers also searched for ...

Answer (score 1):

The simple way to provide an recomendation is to use the build-IN MLT (more like this) feature:
https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/7_5/morelikethis.html

This gives back id's from similar documents. But, this is not an recommendation based on the search of other people. You have to order documents (for example the MLT result list) based, on what other users have "clicked" in relation. Probably, the Re-Ranking feature is interesting for you: https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/7_4/learning-to-rank.html

Finally you have to find out, what doc ids other people have opened after searching an similar term. So if person searches for "blue cars" an other users searched for "cars that are blue" they get (maybe or none)  different docs.

You have to cluster search terms and you have to store and calculate, which documents are clicked in relation to the search term. This means, every click to one doc should update your docs-statistics. This docs statistics is your base for finding and ranking your recommendations.

This means, there is no build-in feature in solr, which provides this all in one. But you could use some of the solr build in feature to implement your own powerful recommendation feature.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to implement that yourself. Solr does not keep any internal logs around for what people have searched for that you can automagically query.

If you set the logging level to INFO, Solr will include each query made in the log file, so you can attempt to parse that and at least know what people have searched for. It won't give you any insight into what documents people where shown and what they clicked on - or what other related items they moved into.

To implement something like that, you'll want to perform the logging yourself, and keep track of which items you show for each query, and attempt to build a decent correlation between objects. There are many ways to do this, but they involve recommendation engines, machine learning, math, etc. - start your adventure by searching for recommendation engine on your search engine of choice and build out from that. There's also many presentations from Lucene Solr Revolution about the subject, for example [Anyone can build a recommendation engine with Solr](https://www.slideshare.net/lucidworks/anyone-can-build-a-recommendation-engine-with-solr-presented-by-doug-turnbull-opensource-connections).